# Passing DOM table variables to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, variables, dynamic

I am not very experienced just a learner.
Now come to the question.
I have a dynamic table codes are below: works fine as intended.

```
    <head>

    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    #tblitemsgrid 
    td { 
    padding: 0.5em; 
    }
    .classy0 { background-color: #234567; color: #89abcd; }
    .classy1 { background-color: #89abcd; color: #234567; }

    th { 
    padding: 0.5em;
    background:#39C;
    text-align:center;




    }

    -->
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var INPUT_NAME_PREFIX = 'input'; // this is being set via script
    var RADIO_NAME = 'totallyrad'; // this is being set via script
    var TABLE_NAME = 'tblitemsgrid'; // this should be named in the HTML
    var ROW_BASE = 1; // first number (for display)
    var hasLoaded = false;

    window.onload=fillInRows;

    function fillInRows()
    {
    hasLoaded = true;
    addRowToTable();

    }

    // CONFIG:
    // myRowObject is an object for storing information about the table rows
    function myRowObject(one, two, three, four, five)
    {
    this.one = one; // text object
    this.two = two; // text object
    this.three = three; // text object
    this.four = four; // text object


    }

    /*
    * insertRowToTable
    * Insert and reorder
    */
    function insertRowToTable()
    {
    if (hasLoaded) {
    var tbl = document.getElementById(TABLE_NAME);
    var rowToInsertAt = tbl.tBodies[0].rows.length;
    for (var i=0; i<tbl.tBodies[0].rows.length; i++) {
    }
    addRowToTable(rowToInsertAt);
    reorderRows(tbl, rowToInsertAt);

    }
    }

    /*
    * addRowToTable

    function addRowToTable(num)
    {
    if (hasLoaded) {
    var tbl = document.getElementById(TABLE_NAME);
    var nextRow = tbl.tBodies[0].rows.length;
    var iteration = nextRow + ROW_BASE;
    if (num == null) { 
    num = nextRow;
    } else {
    iteration = num + ROW_BASE;
    }

    // add the row
    var row = tbl.tBodies[0].insertRow(num);

    // CONFIG: requires classes named classy0 and classy1
    row.className = 'classy' + (iteration % 2);

    // CONFIG: This whole section can be configured

    // cell 0 - text - Serial Number
    var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(iteration);
    cell0.appendChild(textNode);

    // cell 1 - input text - Account name
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
    var txtInpACC = document.createElement('input');
    txtInpACC.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    txtInpACC.setAttribute('name', 'accname' + iteration);
    txtInpACC.setAttribute('size', '40');
    txtInpACC.setAttribute('value', iteration); 
    cell1.appendChild(txtInpACC);

    // cell 2 - input box- Dr amount
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
    var txtInpDR = document.createElement('input');
    txtInpDR.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    txtInpDR.setAttribute('name', 'DrAmount' + iteration);
    txtInpDR.setAttribute('size', '10');
    txtInpDR.setAttribute('value', iteration); // iteration included for debug purposes
    cell2.appendChild(txtInpDR);


    // cell 3 - input box- Cr amount
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
    var txtInpCR = document.createElement('input');
    txtInpCR.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    txtInpCR.setAttribute('name', 'CrAmount' + iteration);
    txtInpCR.setAttribute('size', '10');
    txtInpCR.setAttribute('value', iteration); // iteration included for debug purposes
    cell3.appendChild(txtInpCR);


    // cell 4 - input button - Delete
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(4);
    var btnEl = document.createElement('input');
    btnEl.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    btnEl.setAttribute('value', 'Delete');
    btnEl.onclick = function () {deleteCurrentRow(this)};
    cell4.appendChild(btnEl);


    // Pass in the elements you want to reference later
    // Store the myRow object in each row
    row.myRow = new myRowObject(textNode, txtInpACC, txtInpDR, txtInpCR, btnEl);
    }
    }

    // CONFIG: this entire function is affected by myRowObject settings

    function deleteCurrentRow(obj)
    {
    if (hasLoaded) {
    var oRows = document.getElementById('tblitemsgrid').getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var iRowCount = (oRows.length - 2);

    if (iRowCount <1+1) {
    alert('Your table has ' + iRowCount + ' row(s). Row count can not be zero.');
    return
    }

    var delRow = obj.parentNode.parentNode;
    var tbl = delRow.parentNode.parentNode;
    var rIndex = delRow.sectionRowIndex;
    var rowArray = new Array(delRow);
    deleteRows(rowArray);
    reorderRows(tbl, rIndex);}

    }

    function reorderRows(tbl, startingIndex)
    {
    if (hasLoaded) {
    if (tbl.tBodies[0].rows[startingIndex]) {
    var count = startingIndex + ROW_BASE;
    for (var i=startingIndex; i<tbl.tBodies[0].rows.length; i++) {

    // CONFIG: next line is affected by myRowObject settings
    tbl.tBodies[0].rows[i].myRow.one.data = count; // text

    // CONFIG: next line is affected by myRowObject settings
    tbl.tBodies[0].rows[i].myRow.two.name = INPUT_NAME_PREFIX + count; // input text

    var tempVal = tbl.tBodies[0].rows[i].myRow.two.value.split(' '); 
    tbl.tBodies[0].rows[i].myRow.two.value = count + ' was' + tempVal[0]; 

    // CONFIG: next line is affected by myRowObject settings
    tbl.tBodies[0].rows[i].myRow.four.value = count; // input radio

    // CONFIG: requires class named classy0 and classy1
    tbl.tBodies[0].rows[i].className = 'classy' + (count % 2);

    count++;
    }
    }
    }
    }

    function deleteRows(rowObjArray)
    {
    if (hasLoaded) {
    for (var i=0; i<rowObjArray.length; i++) {
    var rIndex = rowObjArray[i].sectionRowIndex;
    rowObjArray[i].parentNode.deleteRow(rIndex);
    }
    }
    }

    function openInNewWindow(frm)
    {
    // open a blank window
    var aWindow = window.open('', 'TableAddRow2NewWindow',
    'scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,width=400,height=400');

    // set the target to the blank window
    frm.target = 'TableAddRow2NewWindow';

    // submit
    frm.submit();
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="tableaddrow_nw.php" method="get">
    <p>
    <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addRowToTable();" />
    <input type="button" value="Insert [I]" onclick="insertRowToTable();" />
    <!--<input type="button" value="Delete [D]" onclick="deleteChecked();" />-->
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="openInNewWindow(this.form);" />
    </p>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" id="tblitemsgrid" width=600>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th colspan="5">Sample table</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>E.#</th>
    <th>Account name</th>
    <th>Debit</th>
    <th>Credit</th>
    <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is a processing page:

```
    <head>
    <title>Table Add Row - new window</title>
    <script language="JavaScript"> 
    <!--
    function printToPage()
    {
    var pos;
    var searchStr = window.location.search;
    var searchArray = searchStr.substring(1,searchStr.length).split('&');
    var htmlOutput = '';
    for (var i=0; i<searchArray.length; i++) {
    htmlOutput += searchArray[i] + '<br />';
    }
    return(htmlOutput);
    }
    //-->
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <b>MREDKJ's Table Add Row</b>
    <br />
    Below should be the name/value pairs that were submitted:
    <p>
    <script language="JavaScript"> 
    <!--
    document.write(printToPage());
    //-->
    </script>
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

the above displays a result:

```
accname1=1
DrAmount1=1
CrAmount1=1
input2=2+was2
DrAmount2=2
CrAmount2=2
input3=3+was3
DrAmount3=3
CrAmount3=3
input4=4+was4
DrAmount4=4
CrAmount4=4
```

how can I pass javascript variables into PHP (which is server side and client side) in the above case ?
thanks alot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to pass these informations to server easy way

And remember. PHP isn't client side language

```
$.ajax({
       'url': 'ajax.php', 
       'type': 'POST',
       'data': 'accname1='+accname1+'&input1='+input1+'&input2='+input2+'&input3='+input3+'&DrAmount1='+DrAmount1+'&DrAmount2='+DrAmount2+'&DrAmount3='+DrAmount3+'&CrAmount1='+CrAmount1'&CrAmount2='+CrAmount2'&CrAmount3='+CrAmount3,
       'success': function(){
             alert('data sent');
       }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to have the "data" in the above example dynamic values. because user may have five sets of rows to input eg accname1,accname2,accname3 and so on. I hope I am able to explain myself clearly. apologise as I am newbie.

Answer (score 1):

The way to pass variables from client-side to server-side is via HTTP Request. So either you redirect to a PHP page passing in the variable as GET query strings or POST data or you can also do an AJAX call of either GET or POST.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. can you point me to an example please ? Cheers

Comment: @pixelfreak perhaps you could shed some light on this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14165920/1788087